# Nginx convert subdomain to path component without redirect

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, subdomain, roundtrip

The idea is to take incoming requests to `http://abc.example.com/...` and rewrite them to `http://example.com/abc/...`

That's easy enough to do with a 301/302 redirect:

```
# rewrite via 301 Moved Permanently
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name abc.example.com;
  rewrite ^ $scheme://example.com/abc$request_uri permanent;
}
```

The trick is to do this URL change **transparently** to the client when `abc.example.com` and `example.com` point at the same Nginx instance.

Put differently, can Nginx serve the contents from `example.com/abc/...` when `abc.example.com/...` is requested and **without another client round trip**?

**Starting Point Config**

Nginx config that accomplishes the task with a 301:

```
# abc.example.com
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name abc.example.com;
  rewrite ^ $scheme://example.com/abc$request_uri permanent;
}

# example.com
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  location / { 
    # ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
# abc.example.com
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name abc.example.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/abc$request_uri;
    proxy_set_header Host example.com;
  }
}
```

Comment: Works great having Nginx proxy to itself. Changed host to 127.0.0.1 because otherwise Nginx has to resolve the hostname (a whole separate issue). Added `$request_uri` so the path gets appended in the proxy request.

Comment: This works perfectly. Just watch out for static assets that might 404.

Comment: @KJPrince what's the problem with 404 assets?

Comment: This also works if your target host uses SSL - `proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1/abc$request_uri`

Comment: Any solution for multiple subdomains or wildcard subdomains?