# User profile page - subdomain

Tags: django

I need this feature

Users can create an account in my webapp and have their profile page under:

> username.mydomain.com

(subdomain).

How can I do something like this? Where do I start?

Comment: Are you asking how to design your own user model or how to redirect the urls like in the example?

Comment: @yuvi I ask about everything. I don't understand how to begin to design and create such a function (and how to operate on subdomains). How it should work.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I don't think it is easy at all! Why not use a domain/user url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wont write it all for you but here is how I've done it before:

1. DNS must forward all subdomains to your service (A record `*.yourdomain.com` -> your IP address);
2. If you've deployed with Nginx you can use the REGEX URL selector to capture the subdomain (their username) and pass this to your service as a url path (so `username.yourdomain.com` becomes `yourdomain.com/username` without displaying this to the user). [This SO question - Nginx convert subdomain to path component without redirect -](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491944/nginx-convert-subdomain-to-path-component-without-redirect)  should help you.
3. Now it's easy to use Djangos built in URLs to take that username and return the correct profile page.

### Edit 1:

**Bonus**

By default this will create a `404 - Not found` error message if a username is entered that doesn't have their own account. If you use Djangos urls (something like `/users/username/`) you can return a custom `User not found` or similar error message to make the user experience a bit smoother.