# Route subdomain to a path in a Dokku app using Nginx

Tags: nginx, parse-server, dokku

I have a few apps running in a aws instance with Dokku. I'm using virtual hostname, and together with some DNS configuration of my registered domain, I have the following for one of them: `mydomain.com` is a `CNAME` record pointing to the aws instance address, and Dokku+nginx take care of redirecting to the correct app/process.

The path for all API calls is `/parse`, as I'm using the open source Parse Server. The final server url is `mydomain.com/parse`.

What I want to achieve, ideally, is the following: `api.mydomain.com` gets redirected to `mydomain.com/parse`, `api.mydomain.com/someFunction` to `mydomain.com/parse/someFunction` and so on.

When researching to see how this may be possible, I found that this can be done easily with nginx, like explained [here in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491944/nginx-convert-subdomain-to-path-component-without-redirect).

I can even change manually the nginx config file, but I'm afraid that it will be overwritten in future changes. How can this ideally be achieved with `nginx` on Dokku?