# Rewriting subfolder to subdomain without redirect with nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, subdomain, subdirectory

I would like to have requests to `http://example.com/products/some-variable` rewritten to `http://catalog.example.com/some-variable` without redirecting the user. In other words, the URL should not change.

I have found an example where something similar is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491944/nginx-convert-subdomain-to-path-component-without-redirect), but I can't seem to figure out how to do the opposite.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in your case it would be something like this:

```
server {

  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  location ~ ^/products/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass http://catalog.example.com/$1;
  }

}
```

Here is the article with `proxy_pass` examples:

http://www.liaohuqiu.net/posts/nginx-proxy-pass/