# How to use django-hosts with Nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx, subdomain, django-hosts

I have created one Django app which has two apps named "api" and "consumer". Now I want to use subdomains for both of this app. Like **api.server.com** and **server.com**. I searched online and found django-hosts so I implemented in my localhost and its working fine.

After that I deployed it on AWS EC2 instance and created subdomain in Godaddy and point both root domain and subdomain to my instance IP. Root domain is working fine but when I try to go **api.server.com**, it shows me default **Welcome to Nginx** screen. Please help me with this issue.

**nginx.conf**

```
server{
    server_name server.com, api.server.com;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/path/to/static/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/username/project/project.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think its due to `,` in the server_name: check https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html. Also, you don't have to use a plugin (django-hosts) to assign different domain names to different paths.:  Create 2 different ngnix configs like this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/14492755/1771949

Comment: @Rohith I saw that link but I think its different from mine because I am using gunicorn socket file for this. Can you please let me know how to rewrite using the socket file?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `,` a simple space will do.

```
server_name server.com  api.server.com;
```

Also you can use wildcards, see [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html).

```
server_name *.server.com;
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. Now I am able to access my site using the subdomain but @Rohith mentioned that I need to rewrite url for this but I am using gunicorn socket file for this. Can you please let me know how to rewrite using the socket file?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a plugin (like django-hosts) to achieve what you are trying to do. Create 2 different nginx configurations for each subdomain you want to create (server.com and api.server.com), and forward requests from `api.server.com` to `/api` URL and request from `server.com` to `/`.  Following is a basic example.

server.com

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name server.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000$request_uri;
    }

}
```

api.server.com

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name api.server.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/api$request_uri;
    }

}
```

I recommend not to depend on 3rd party plugins unnecessarily. Refer https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/ for more details.

Comment: I have already tried this but I am using sock file for "proxy_pass". You solution didn't work for me because of this.